# Dependency Injection outside a constructor in Server-side Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

I want to use a scoped service in a method of a singleton service in server-side Blazor.
I found out that you can use the `[FromServices]` Attribute in the function parameters, but when I call the method I get a compiler error for calling the method with less parameters.
I tried calling the method with a dummy parameter in the hope it would get overwritten when called, but that was not the case.

Scoped Service:

```
public class UserContext
{
    public string SomeUserRelatedData {get; set;}
}
```

Singleton service:

```
public class GlobalService
{
    ...
    public void DoSomethingWithUserData([FromServices]UserContext usercontext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton<GlobalService>();
        services.AddScoped<UserContext>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this only works in Controllers? _"Specifies that an action parameter should be bound using the **request** services."_ - [FromServicesAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't do that.

You can use this `[FromServices]` only in the method that is called by the framework. In this case in any action from a controller or in `Invoke` method in middleware.

But there is a solution to your problem. I assume that the method that calls `DoSomethingWithUserData` is scope. In that class ( or method if it's an endpoint ) you can inject your `UserContext` and call the method from `GlobalService` with that instance.